# Send file with details from server to client and vice versa in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to send a file from Server to Client and Client to server in Netty.
I am using a ChunkedFileHandler() to send files. I can receive the bytebuf object and can assemble them and create the file

My question is how to know when the file sending process in completed, name of the file which is being sent and what is the size of the file?

I know we need to send all these details but there are no proper examples for this.

Thanks